# WAMP localhost install SQLSRV for connecting to database

Tags: php, wamp, sqlsrv

I'm using WAMP to run my code locally.
Now I want to connect to a microsoft SQL server database using `PHP`.

```
// connection with callstats DB
$serverName = "IP, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"CDR", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
```

Im using:

```
$conn_CDR = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$params = array();
```

And then for a query:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn_CDR, "", $params);
```

But then I get this error:

> Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Now I know I need to install sqlsrv into my localhost.
I'm using `PHP 7.2.14` so I installed `php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll` to my `C:\localhost\bin\php\php7.2.14`.
Also I added this line to my `php.ini`.

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll
```

Then I restarted my WAMPserver, and runned my code again, but I still get the same result.
I also tried adding the file to `C:\localhost\bin\apache\apache2.4.37\bin`but no succes either.
Does anyone know why this error keeps occurring and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show how you create $serverName and  $connectionInfo - you can anonymise the data

Comment: added my $connectioninfo

Comment: @Jbadminton Please, execute `if ($conn_CDR === false) {echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);};` after `sqlsrv_connect()` and post the error. Probably `sqlsrv_connect()` fails. Thanks.

Comment: Error (sqlsrv_connect): Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 )

Comment: @Jbadminton You  need to download and install the ODBC driver. PHP Driver for SQL Server (php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll) needs this driver to run correctly. Thanks.

Comment: As in my question I already did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing the `Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server` onto my computer.
Then I restarted my WAMP server and it worked!
[Download ODBC Driver here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567)

This gave me the info I needed to solve my error:

```
if ($conn_CDR === false) {echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$conn_CDR = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$params = array();
$sql = "your sql query";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn_CDR, $sql, $params));
```

See the manual here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

like this example:-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)";
$params = array(1, "some data");

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: This code is almost the same as I have and your code does generate some syntax errors

Comment: @Jbadminton if This code is almost the same as I have ,it same as from php.net mannual , then why you down vote me?

Comment: as your code is not the answer and almost the same as the question

Comment: this is your code $result = sqlsrv_query($conn_CDR, "", $params); check this where is 2 argument here?

Comment: I know how to use sqlsrv but not how to install it

Comment: I emptied the query, so that are these "" for